# getchar following scanf (to read an integer) takes terminating "enter" key of scanf as character

Tags: c, scanf

When I have a scanf followed by a getchar, why does the getchar always keep getting the last delimiting character of scanf? How can I stop that? I tried looking into "format specifiers" for scanf, read quite a few things but none solves this.

The code is shown below -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    char b;

    printf ("Enter an integer \n");
    scanf_s(" %d", &a);

    printf("Enter a character \n");
    b = getchar();

    printf("The integer you entered is %d \n", a);
    printf("The character you entered is %c \n", b);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as below - 
*Enter an integer
4563
Enter a character
The integer you entered is 4563
The character you entered is*

The enter key I press at the end of integer entry is being returned by getchar. The screen does not even stop after printing "Enter a character". What is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: #1 Don't mix scanf and other input function

Comment: the delimiter character (often a newline) is NOT input by a call to `scanf()` but rather left in stdin.   Easiest/typical way to eliminate the delimiter character is to follow the call to `scanf()` with something like: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != 'delimiter' ) ;`  Usually the delimiter is the newline so 'delimiter' would be '\n'`

Comment: @user3629249 : Adding dummy getchar just to avoid the delimiter - is it not a patch ? Does it not have side effects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `scanf(" %c", &b)` instead of `getchar()`

When you put the space befor the `%c` you clean the buffer

Or you can clean the buffer using this too:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

Complete example:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter an integer \n");
    int a;
    scanf(" %d", &a);
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    }

    printf("Enter a character \n");
    char b = getchar();

    printf("The integer you entered is %d \n", a);
    printf("The character you entered is %c \n", b);

    _getch();
}
```

But I think the `scanf()`

Comment: the space will consume an 'white space' so if the delimiter was 'white space' that will work great.  If the delimiter was something else, this will not work

Comment: Hum, can you give me an example?

Comment: I check the error, if my input was "22 2"  the `scanf` jumps and print `The integer you entered is 22``
The character you entered is 2`

Comment: scanf with a space before the format specifier is doing what I was trying to do. Though tt does not handle cases when my character is a space or enter or tab i.e. any of the blank spaces.

Comment: Nice @BhawandeepSingh, and thanks for the editing **Stargateur**

Comment: BTW, you didn't finish your last sentence and `getchar()` return an `int`

Comment: Good use of `int` with `int ch;`.  Code should use `int` with `char b = getchar();`.

Comment: @Stargateur :  Adding dummy getchar just to avoid the delimiter - is it not a patch ? Does it not have side effects ?

Comment: @chux : What are the disadvantages of using char rather than int for char b?

Comment: @BhawandeepSingh Consider `getchar();` typically can return 256 different `unsigned char` values or the negative `EOF`.  By saving those 257 potentially different values in an 8-bit `char`, some information is lost.  With `EOF == -1`, how does code recall that the `getchar()` return value was 255 or -1?  Even worse, when `char` is  an _unsigned char_,   with `char b;`, `while (b != EOF)` is never true.  Also, `is...()` functions are well defined for the return values of `getchar()`, not all the negative values of `char` - which is UB.